# Insert Rows in the Database which should be conditional if exist then update value else insert

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4, upsert

I have function where I insert rows in mapping table without any validation but I am facing an issue that if the value already exist in the database, it should update a flag of isactive to true instead of inserting a new rows in database.

Postgres version is 9.4 and below is my function to insert records:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cloudschema.org_retailer_map(
j integer[],
l integer[])
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

insert into retailer_org_map(org_id,supplier_id,isactive)(
SELECT org_id[i],supplier_id[i],isactive[1]
FROM (
SELECT generate_series(1, array_upper(org_id, 1)) AS i,supplier_id,org_id,isactive
FROM (SELECT $1 supplier_id ,$2 org_id,ARRAY[true] isactive) t) t);

return 1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: add UK on columns and `exception when UK violated update` to function

Comment: See here for many answers to that question including workarounds for old Postgres versions that do not support `insert on conflict` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+upsert